# Create lists or tibble of formulas using vectors of X & Y

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, tibble, rep

I need to create a list of formulas to be later used in a map function. I have the vectors Y and X

```
X <- c("A", "B", "C")
Y <- c("X", "L", "Z")
```

and want to use these vectors to get the output as 3 different lists of length 9 or a tibble with the desired output shown below. Can we use `rep(X, n)` to get the multiple entries of X and `!(X %in% "C")` to remove "C" when Y==L and "B" when Y==Z and `reformulate(X,Y)` to create formula?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will create your target output in one go:

```
# X <- c("A", "B", "C")
# Y <- c("X", "L", "Z")

data.frame(Y = rep(Y, each = 3), 
           X = I(rep(append(list(X), 
                            c(data.frame(combn(X, 2)[1:2, 1:2], 
                                     stringsAsFactors = F))), each = 3))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(formula = paste("X ~", paste(X, collapse = " + "))) %>% 
  data.frame()

#   Y       X       formula
# 1 X A, B, C X ~ A + B + C
# 2 X A, B, C X ~ A + B + C
# 3 X A, B, C X ~ A + B + C
# 4 L    A, B     X ~ A + B
# 5 L    A, B     X ~ A + B
# 6 L    A, B     X ~ A + B
# 7 Z    A, C     X ~ A + C
# 8 Z    A, C     X ~ A + C
# 9 Z    A, C     X ~ A + C
```